# Laravel 8.0 Warning with Nexmo-Bridge

Tags: php, laravel, cron, vonage

i have a problem since upgrading to laravel 8.0 with vonage/Nexmo. The website still works but CronJobs doesn't work (because of the Warning probably?).

Here is the Warning that appears in the Apache Error log:

Got error 'PHP message: PHP Warning:  file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/autoload.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/webapps/preprod/:/var/lib/php/session:/tmp) in **/home/webapps/preprod/vendor/vonage/nexmo-bridge/src/Autoloader.php on line 69**

**My composer.json:**
"require": {
"php": "^7.3|^8.0",
"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3.1|^7.0.1",
"nexmo/laravel": "^2.4.1",
**"vonage/nexmo-bridge": "^0.1.0"** (this one was added after upgrading but the problem is still there)

I have tried to add the folder to the open_dir directory, but the warning is still there.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Or is it possible to make Cronjob ignore the Warnings?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

After removing line 69 everything works.
I had wrong php version on server too (so i had to update that too).

I will retry later if the error is still there with the good php version.

Comment: What was the line 69 ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been fixed with the latest update of `vonage-php-nexmo-bridge`. Just upgrade to [version 0.1.2](https://github.com/Nexmo/vonage-php-nexmo-bridge/releases/tag/0.1.2).